# hash map fast inserts but slow retrieval

Tags: c++, performance, hashmap

I am using google's implementation of the hash map
google::dense_hash_map.

Mine is a clustering application.  So I have to store distances between pairs of clusters.  Each cluster has a cluster id which is a long int.  So the key has to be (long int id1, long int id2);

So I decided that I need a hashMap inside a hashMap for this to work.

This is the structure of my distance storing hash map:

```
    google::dense_hash_map<long int, google::dense_hash_map<long int, double> > distanceHash;
```

This is the code to insert a distance into the hash map and retrieve it

```
template<class Point>
void CoverTree<Point>:: insertDistance(long int id1, long int id2, long double distance)
{

  //Always id1 < id2;
  if(id1 < id2)
  {
    long temp = id1;
    id1 = id2;
    id2 = temp;
  }


  if(distanceHash.find(id1) == distanceHash.end())
  {
    google::dense_hash_map<long int, double> insideHash;
    insideHash.set_empty_key(-9999  );
    insideHash[id2] = distance;
    distanceHash[id1] = insideHash;
  }
  else
  {
    (distanceHash[id1])[id2] = (distanceHash[id1])[id2];
  }
}

template<class Point>
double CoverTree<Point>::getStoredDistance(long int id1, long int id2)
{
  if(id1 < id2)
  {
    long temp = id1;
    id1 = id2;
    id2 = temp;
  }

  google::dense_hash_map<long int, double>::iterator it;

  if(distanceHash.find(id1) != distanceHash.end())
  {

    if( distanceHash[id1].find(id2) != distanceHash[id1].end() ) 
      return distanceHash[id1][id2];
  }

  return -1;
}
```

I have millions of distances.  LasTime I checked ,there were roughly 600000000 distances of which 400000000 were unique.  This means that 1/3rd of the distances are repeated and that time can be saved.

But when I use this hash map structure to store the distances, the program runs way slower.  This is what I exactly find:
If I just store the distances using the distance function, then the whole program runs about 50 seconds slower. (200 secs with storage and 150 without).
But If I store the distances and then use the hashmap to check whether the distances exist before computing them, the program becomes way way slower(1/25th of the program takes 300 seconds).

I dont understand this behaviour.  I would guess that once the distances are stored, it should be faster to retrieve the distances.  Please let me know what is wrong here and if it can be made faster.

P.S: RAM is not an issue.  I am running this on a server with around 160 gigs of RAM. And the peak memory consumption when the hashmap is used is only 1.8% of the total memory(saw that using top).  So paging and thrashing should not be an issue.

Comment: Is getStoredDistance(long int id1, long int id2) slow?

Comment: You are using distanceHash.find(id1) N times? What is its complexity? N*N ? Then you put another N and it becomes O(N*N*N)

Comment: yes getStoredDistance is slow.  I see how that can be the case.  I have an idea that might solve this.  I will have a hash table within each point.  That hash table stores the distances to all nodes from that particular node.  This will eliminate the istanceHash.find(id1) as I know the node for which I need the distance.

Comment: DO you think that would work?  I ll try it out tomorrow morning and update it here.

Comment: You are right. Sorting could fix this also.

Answer (score 0):

`But If I store the distances and then use the hashmap to check whether the distances exist before computing them, the program becomes way way slower(1/25th of the program takes 300 seconds).`

I suspect you are finding all the elements to approve the data.

Okay, hashmap lookup time complexity is O(n), but you are using

```
distanceHash.find(id1)
```

twice in the `getStoredDistance` function n times, which makes the total complexity O(n*n) for the worst case

400M * 400M = 160000000000000000 too complex